# App not displaying correctly on Samsung Transform

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas, android-bitmap

My game, **Hidden Treasures**, has been on the market over two months now. Recently a customer presented a new problem that has never happened before.

According to the customer, 
In their words:

> "There was a diagonal line across it, and it was like
>   the image was backward so that the right side of the line showed what
>   was supposed to be on the left, and the left side showed what was
>   really on the right. Like if you switched them, it would show the
>   proper image. The image itself is slanted as well (from top left to
>   bottom right, at the same angle as the division line)"

[image]
[image]

I have never heard of this before, and have no idea how to fix it.
The app is a hidden object game, it uses a `canvas` for all the drawing as I did not know `OpenGL ES` at the time I made this game.

Basically, its got two `bitmaps`,

1. the size of the screen,
2. 1680x1050.

> It draws a chunk from the big one onto the small one, then it draws all the hidden objects over that, then displays it to the screen.

I don't understand how it could even mess up at all. Its drawing a screen sized image to the screen, and it doesn't happen on any other phone to my knowledge.

Any ideas? It doesn't force close so I don't have a stack trace

Comment: I havent worked a lot with canvases personally so this may be an off the wall comment, but is there a way, like with views in relative layouts, to set the alignment of the canvas and bitmap on it? Like bitmap.alignCanvas